# Delayed_job is not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I implemented the delayed job & it is processing fine but it is generating the mails in development.log not in production.log.

Also no mail is actually sent, it's just generating in development log. After processing I have no job in delayed job table also.

I also used `RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work` but still the mail is in development log and is not actually sent; I am using mail server on Ubuntu to send mails.

I have noticed that `rake jobs:work` by default uses the development log don't know is it same for the production server too?

If somebody know the problem then please answer ASAP because my application has been stuck due to this on the production server and lots of mails are just going in development log and not actually going to the end user.

Comment: Add `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false` in file `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` and restart app/server. Setting that will not delete any jobs that have an error in them, that might help narrow down the problem. To find jobs with errors : `select id,last_error from delayed_jobs where last_error is not null;`. You should not be using `rake jobs:work` in production. Best to make a monit file for it.

Comment: i am using RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work but after this mails are only in development log but actually they were not sent to the receiver

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but in your config/production.rb, have you set

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

It's possible you set the delivery method in config/development.rb, but forgot to do the same in the production environment. Please let me know so I can help further!